# mod_rewrite in .htaccess causes header not to be applied - why?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, cache, httpd.conf

Excerpt from `<VirtualHost *:80>` section in `httpd.conf` (goal: set `Cache-Control` for *all* JavaScript files):

```
<LocationMatch "\.js">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</LocationMatch>
```

`.htaccess` (part of Symfony PHP framework):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, I checked the `Cache-Control` header with two different URLs pointing at the *same* resource:

1. `/index.php/pt_BR/home_page.js`: `Cache-Control` set as specified above
2. `/pt_BR/home_page.js`: `Cache-Control` with some other value

Now, why is the `Cache-Control` header not set for `/pt_BR/home_page.js`?

Note that there is *no* query string involved, and `<LocationMatch "\.js">` matches before *and* after rewrite.

Comment: Is there a file in `<DocumentRoot>/pt_BR/home_page.js` ?  The `RewriteCond` depends on this.

Comment: @Ladadadada: No, no file in that location. Note that I am using `LocationMatch`, not `FilesMatch`.

Comment: @feklee Is it supposed to be rewriting to just `index.php` without appending what was captured from the original string?  The rewritten request URL doesn't contain `.js` anywhere if that last `RewriteRule` directive hits.

Comment: @Shane Madden: You are right - it's very simple. The URLs (`/index.php/pt_BR/home_page.js`, `/pt_BR/home_page.js`) get rewritten to `/index.php?pt_BR/home_page.js`. And then: `LocationMatch` doesn't match anymore, because it doesn't match query strings.

Comment: The `LocationMatch` and the front controller rewrite apply in both cases, however, and you are getting different results for them.  Since the file doesn't exist, symfony *must* be serving both cases.  My guess (and this is *just* a guess) is that both requests get the `Cache-Control` header from your `LocationMatch` but symfony overrides one of them later on in the processing of the request.  You would need to ask a symfony expert why that might be.  The key here is that I think *symfony* is the difference, not Apache.

Comment: That's right - I said that the results are different. Have to think about that...

Comment: @feklee Can you turn on a `RewriteLog` file and set `RewriteLogLevel 9` for a couple test requests?  A request with `/index.php/` in there as if it were a directory gets mapped to the file in the php handler - but I'm not sure if that fulfills the `-f` rewrite condition.  We might as well get a look at what it's actually doing under the hood with the debug log.

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging

Need to head out now, I hope I'll have more time to explain later how this plays together.

Comment: Further explanation would be great! I don't see how merging could be the cause of the described behavior. I also read the *Technical Note* but it only leaves me puzzled.